# Raycasthit2d is not detecting any collisons

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've done some googling and can't figure out why this isn't working.

This is part of a dash ability that checks for collisions. it returns a bool so if true then I can dash and if false I cannot dash.

Here is my code.

All of the debugs are logging what they should be except no matter what it returns true.

```
private bool CanMove(GameObject parent, Vector3 dir, float dis)
    {
        RaycastHit2D rayCastHit = Physics2D.Raycast(parent.GetComponent<Transform>().position, dir, dis, Enemies);

        Debug.Log(parent.GetComponent<Transform>().position);
        Debug.Log(dir);
        Debug.Log(dis);

        if (rayCastHit.collider == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("true");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("false");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here is a picture of me testing. This shows the log after I've dashed through a wall, which I shouldn't have been able to dash through.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGc4E.png

Comment: Is the wall in the `Enemies` LayerMask? The screenshot you provided printed `true` meaning that nothing was detected.

Comment: No, it's the obstacles layermask, but I tried with no layer mask at all and that doesn't work either.

Comment: You did add colliders to the walls and all obstacles, right? Can you post a screenshot of the wall in the Inspector?

Comment: I have colliders on everything else. It is all working correctly. I believe there was an issue because of a rigidbody component. However I have since removed the large collider entirely because I don't think it was the right way to approach my issue. So I'm all set. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are using 2d colliders, right? BoxCollider2D instead of BoxCollider? The 2d and 3d physics systems are separate

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the large collider colliding with a rigidbody2d component. I've since removed the large collider entirely because it was a bad solution to my problem to begin with.